# How can i sum float values in nvarchar field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following weight calculation in sql server,  which is if any of the weight fields are NULL display 'NMI' otherwise sum the weight. All weight fields displayed below are are nvarchar datatype such as `[TIREWGHT],[WHLWGHT],[VALVEWGHT],[BOMPART1WGHT],[BOMPART2WGHT],[BOMPART3WGHT],[BOMPART4WGHT],[BOMPART5WGHT]`

here is the condition i want to use in the calculation

```
if ([BOM-TIRE]  IS NOT NULL  AND T1.[TIREWGHT] IS NULL) OR 
([BOM-WHEEL] IS NOT NULL AND T1.[WHLWGHT] IS NULL  ) OR 
([BOM-VALVE] IS NOT NULL AND [VALVEWGHT] IS NULL) OR 
([BOM-PART 1] IS NOT NULL AND [BOMPART1WGHT] IS NULL) OR 
([BOM-PART 2] IS NOT NULL AND [BOMPART2WGHT] IS NULL) OR 
([BOM-PART 3] IS NOT NULL AND [BOMPART3WGHT] IS NULL) OR
([BOM-PART 4] IS NOT NULL AND [BOMPART4WGHT] IS NULL) OR
([BOM-PART 5] IS NOT NULL AND [BOMPART5WGHT] IS NULL)  then display `NMI`
otherwise [TIREWGHT]+[WHLWGHT]+[VALVEWGHT]+[BOMPART1WGHT]+[BOMPART2WGHT],[BOMPART3WGHT]+[BOMPART4WGHT]+[BOMPART5WGHT] .
```

Note: `NMI` stand for Need more info

**i tried weight calculation**

```
UPDATE T1
SET [WGHT] = convert (float,    T1.[TIREWGHT]) + 
             convert (float,     T1.[WHLWGHT]) + 
             convert (float,   T1.[VALVEWGHT]) +
             convert (float, T1.[BOMPART1WGHT])+ 
             convert (float, T1.[BOMPART2WGHT])+ 
             convert (float, T1.[BOMPART3WGHT])+ 
             convert (float, T1.[BOMPART4WGHT])+ 
             convert (float, T1.[BOMPART5WGHT])
```

i tried using `CASE` but i get

> error conversion errors

**sample data**

```
[TIREWGHT]  [WHLWGHT]   [VALVEWGHT]  [BOMPART1WGHT]  [BOMPART2WGHT]  [BOMPART3WGHT]   [BOMPART5WGHT]     [BOMPART5WGHT]
143         33           NULL             2.8              2.8           2.8            2.8                  2.8
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are aiming for the same column to return a VARCHAR value ('NMI') in some cases, and a numeric (or FLOAT) value in other cases. You should not do this.

Instead, create a second column to return the NMI value when one or more of your columns contain a null value.

It could look something like this, depending on your exact needs:

```
SELECT [WGHT] = convert (DECIMAL(10,4),    ISNULL(T1.[TIREWGHT],0)) + 
         convert (DECIMAL(10,4),     ISNULL(T1.[WHLWGHT],0)) + 
         convert (DECIMAL(10,4),   ISNULL(T1.[VALVEWGHT],0)) +
         convert (DECIMAL(10,4), ISNULL(T1.[BOMPART1WGHT],0))+ 
         convert (DECIMAL(10,4), ISNULL(T1.[BOMPART2WGHT],0))+ 
         convert (DECIMAL(10,4), ISNULL(T1.[BOMPART3WGHT],0))+ 
         convert (DECIMAL(10,4), ISNULL(T1.[BOMPART4WGHT],0))+ 
         convert (DECIMAL(10,4), ISNULL(T1.[BOMPART5WGHT],0)),
[FulfillsCriteria] = CASE 
    WHEN TIREWGHT IS NULL OR 
        WHLWGHT  IS NULL OR 
        VALVEWGHT IS NULL OR 
        BOMPART1WGHT IS NULL OR 
        BOMPART2WGHT IS NULL OR 
        BOMPART3WGHT IS NULL OR 
        BOMPART4WGHT IS NULL OR 
        BOMPART5WGHT IS NULL
    THEN 'NMI'
    ELSE '' END
```

Comment: Thank you. Its an update statement on trigger i get `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ASSYWGHT, Line 25
Invalid column name 'FulfillsCriteria'.`

Comment: You need to ensure that the table you are updating contains this column before executing an UPDATE statement that tries to update the column. I.e. you need to add the FulfillsCriteria VARCHAR(3) column to your table, and then try to execute the UPDATE statement again.

Answer (score 0):

To convert nvarchar into number and save it in nvarchar field, use `cast`

example :

```
declare @a NVARCHAR(100), @b NVARCHAR(100), @c NVARCHAR(100), @d NVARCHAR(100)
SET @a = '100'
SET @b = '200'
SET @c = NULL

Select @d = CAST(@a as float)+ CAST(@b as float)+  CAST(ISNULL(@c,0) as float);
select @d;
```

`ISNULL` is to handle your NULL